# selenium --headless Chrome Canary

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

Как использовать `selenium` с аргументом `--headless` для Chrome Canary и где взять webdrive для него?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
c = Options()
c.add_argument('--headless')
d = webdriver.Chrome(options=c)
d.get('https://yandex.ru/')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете попросить `ChromeDriver` использовать исполняемый файл `Chrome` в нестандартном месте.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome.exe");
```

`add_argument('--headless')` работает так же.

А webdriver тут - https://chromedriver.chromium.org/chromedriver-canary

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ChromeDriver Canary имеет новейшие функции ChromeDriver. Новые двоичные файлы создаются и становятся доступными несколько раз в день.

**Предупреждаем**: он разработан для разработчиков и первых пользователей и иногда может полностью выйти из строя.

Вы можете найти сборки ChromeDriver Canary по следующим URL-адресам:

- Linux (64-разрядная версия):  https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/
- Mac OS X (64-разрядная версия):  https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/
- Windows (32-разрядная версия):  https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/

Comment: Когда переходишь по ссылке для скачивания веб - драйвера canary, там открывается непонятно что что, пожалуйста, скажите как там разобраться

Comment: обновил ответ, добавил ссылки и скриншот страницы

Comment: Добавил скриншот в вопрос. Что это такое? Появляется при переходе по вашей ссылке.

Comment: список версий. например 100012 от 2011-09-07. а chromedriver.exe который вам требуется расположен в директории 100012/`chrome-win32.test`

Comment: либо `chrome.exe` из архива chrome-win32.zip